# Join relation on itself and pull distinct rows

Tags: postgresql

I have relation A (reviewer_id, book_id, trivalFields)
Suppose at only 1 or 2 reviews exist for the book_id.
I would like a result set that
review_id (first), review_id (second), book_id.
Example:

```
  johnson, smith, 'horton hears a who' 
  johnson, smith, 'green eggs and ham'.
```

But not

```
  johnson, smith, 'horton hears a who' 
  smith, johnson,  'horton hears a who' 
  johnson, smith, 'green eggs and ham'.
  smith, johnson,  'green eggs and ham'.
```

I know how do something like this with brute strength code - but how to do it in pure SQL??

PostgreSQL - by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.reviewer_id AS first, 
       t2.reviewer_id AS second, 
       t1.book_id
FROM table AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t2.book_id = t1.book_id 
                     AND t2.reviewer_id > t1.reviewer_id
```

or

```sql
SELECT MIN(reviewer_id) AS first, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(reviewer_id) > 1 
            THEN MAX(reviewer_id) 
            ELSE NULL
            END AS second, 
       book_id
FROM table
GROUP BY book_id
```

Comment: Brilliant !!!!!